# Deserializing read-only collection with JSON.net

Tags: c#, json.net

Using JSON.net (Newtonsoft), given the following model:

```
public class MainModel
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<SubModel> Subs { get; } 
    = new (new SubModel[] { new(1, 2), new(3, 4) });
}

public class SubModel
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    internal SubModel(int a, int b) => (A, B) = (a, b);
}
```

i'm trying to find a way to deserialize into an existing object graph, using JsonConvert.PopulateObject, which will:

- Reuse both existing objects and collections
- NOT try to append to existing collection instances
- NOT try to create new SubModel instances (no default constructor anyway)
- NOT try to create new Collection instances (collection is readonly, and no setter on Subs)
- Basically just dump a json string over an existing structure, replacing only the "leaf" values (in this case, properties A and B)

In my specific use case this should be possible as the Subs collection is always fixed-size and i control both the input and output.

However while this:

```
var model1 = new MainModel();
model1.Subs[1].B = 5;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model1);
var model2 = new MainModel();
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, model2);
```

produces the correct result for serialization:

```
{"Subs":[{"A":1,"B":2},{"A":3,"B":5}]}
```

model2.Subs[1].B is still '4' after deserialization.

At first I thought I could fix this using a custom converter like so:

```
public class SubListConverter : JsonConverter<ReadOnlyCollection<SubModel>>
{
    public override ReadOnlyCollection<SubModel> ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        ReadOnlyCollection<SubModel> existingValue,
        bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // whatever, doesn't get called anyway
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, ReadOnlyCollection<SubModel> value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach(var sub in value)
            serializer.Serialize(writer, sub);
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}

public class MainModel
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SubListConverter))]
    public ReadOnlyCollection<SubModel> Subs { get; } 
    = new (new SubModel[] { new(1, 2), new(3, 4) });
}
```

But while WriteJson is called as expected, ReadJson is not called during deserialization.
I also tried to play around with the ObjectCreationHandling settings, but that seems primarily useful (in the case of collections) for either replacing the collection object itself, or appending to an existing collection. I want neither of those, i want to overwrite (not replace) the existing objects that are already in the collection.

My question basically boils down to this:

Can I use JSON.net (one way or another, be it converters, contract resolvers, whatever) to overwite an existing object graph, leaving all object references intact, and only replace the primitives (ok also strings, enums etc) at the very leaf ends of the graph, given that I know for a fact that all arrays in the json string and all collections in the object graph are of the same exact fixed size? Bonus points if it does not require json annotations on the model (in fact, serialization should preferrably be handled in a different assembly).

Comment: I don't use the Json serializer, so can't speak to it specifically, but most serializers (that I am aware of) use Reflection to get a list of public variables and properties that are writable. Meaning if they are readonly they aren't retrieved in reflection. I could be completely wrong though.

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://talkdotnet.wordpress.com/2019/03/15/newtonsoft-json-deserializing-objects-that-have-private-setters/

Comment: Since your property doesn't have a setter it basically has a private setter than can only be set via the constructor. So it might be as simple as adding a private set and a [JsonProperty] to it...

Comment: Thing is, I don't want it to have any setter at all, not even private. The reason being that in the real model, various event handlers are wired up from the main to the submodels. This works fine using ObjectCreationHandling.Reuse for regular object types, but somehow not for collections.

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks a million. Negative score causes the question to hide from the search results somehow, unless you specifically request to see 'newest'.

Comment: Well thats a bit too much :) I just think downvoters should be required to explain, so no downvotes without comments. Anyway, repaid the favor. Your question did seem honest and well thought through so i figured, why not.

Comment: @SjoerdvanKreel Thank you. I thought that may have been you. Hope you get a good answer to your question.